How do I project this object onto this hemisphere?
I'm not sure why I can't project this object onto a hemisphere, using a Shrinkwrap modifier. Whenever I try to it project it goes only onto one face of the hemisphere. Why is this?
https://justpaste.it/1paa8

you should rotate your object so that it "looks" to the sphere (rotate on y 90 degrees). if this doesn't help, pls provide blend file so that we know all technical details and can help you in detail.
